# Where can I find an Iranian test answer?

Tags: reference-request, contest-math

Ask who has the official answer to the Iranian third round test question, or the official link, although this is not a mathematical problem, but this problem has been plagued by me, and every time I see the Iranian third round of mathematics test questions published on the [aops](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3322_iran_mo_3rd_round), I find many questions very difficult. I can't do it, although some of the questions are discussed, but they are not correct. I hope someone can help me,I hope we have Iranian friends here. Thank you.

Comment: I'm very interested as well. Maybe for specific questions, you could ask here or re-ask on AOPS if something hasn't received enough attention.

Comment: Related: http://mathysc.ir/problems/

Comment: unfortunately there isn't any official source for iranian third rounds olympiad.we ask to committee to publish an official version of problems at least in persian but apparently they have other priorities.